# Use of & in operator overloading

Tags: c++, operators, overloading

I just saw this piece of code:

```
float& operator [] (int);
```

Id like to know why should I use this &, once there are some overloaders which dont use it.
Thanks!

Comment: It is just a return type of `operator[]` - and this is a reference to float.

Answer (score 3):

`float& operator [] (int)` provides indexed **read/write** access to the object's internal data.  The data is returned by reference so the caller can assign a value to it, eg:

```
class myClass {
private:
    float arr[10];
public:
    float& operator[](int index) { return arr[index]; }
};

myClass m;
float f = m[index];
m[index] = 123.45; // m.arr updated!
```

`float operator [] (int)`, on the other hand, provides indexed **read-only** access to the object's data. The data is returned by value so the caller receives a *copy* of the data and cannot assign a value back to the data inside the object.

```
class myClass {
private:
    float arr[10];
public:
    float operator[](int index) const { return arr[index]; }
};

myClass m;
float f = m[index];
m[index] = 123.45; // m.arr not updated!
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to think about how the operator is used. Consider `std::vector` as an example. It probably (implementation details aside) implements its `operator[]` function like so:

```
T & operator[](size_t index) {
    return *(__internal_heap_allocated_array_ptr + index);
}
```

So that when you call `my_array[4] = 7`, it returns the actual physical location of index 4, allowing you to assign values to it.

Now imagine what would happen if it were written like this:

```
T operator[](size_t index) {
    return *(__internal_heap_allocated_array_ptr + index);
}
```

If you attempted to execute the same code, `my_array[4] = 7`, you'd get a compilation error, and for good reason: you're attempting to assign a value to a *copy* of the value you accessed, which isn't allowed in c++ (you can't assign values to pure rvalues) and even if it were allowed, it wouldn't change the value in the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

This operator returns by reference (`&`), so that you can change the value by assignment, like so `object[0] = obj.data;`.